# How is the 2016 Zurich Chess Challenge "new classical" format different from rapid chess?

Tags: tournament, time-control, rapid

For the upcoming (2016) Zurich Chess Challenge, a new time control will be put in place. According to chess24,

> Six players including former World Champions Vladimir Kramnik and Viswanathan Anand compete in a "new classical" and blitz round-robin event with a novel format and time control.

which is later clarified as

> A five round-robin tournament in which players receive 40 minutes plus 10 seconds per move for the entire game.

How is this different from a standard rapid time control? And will this section of the tournament affect the players' classical ELO rating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not different from rapid chess and will be rated only for the rapid Elo.

The name "new classical" is part of a push to shorten the classical time controls. Originally the idea was to have a time control with around 60 min per game, but in the end they decided to shorten it a little to make the games eligible for the rapid rating at least.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit different from standard rapid chess because it is longer than the usual time controls used.

In the last World Rapid Championship, held in Berlin, the time control was of [15 minutes plus 10 second per move](https://www.fide.com/FIDE/handbook/WorldRapidBlitzChampionshipsRegulations.pdf) and it is also usual to held tournaments with 25'+5" time controls (like the rapid in the GCT tiebreaks).

The ratings calculations will be done using the rapid rating list.